# Can Server.MapPath used in c# files?

Tags: c#

i was trying to get physical path of a file, and got the information that `Server.MapPath` will give you. But for me in my windowform i am not getting that even i used namespace using `System.Web;` but still not getting? 
for example if i have a file named "myTestClass.xml" somewhere in my system, and i need to get the physical path, what i need to do in button click event

Comment: You do not need Server.MapPath() inside a desktop application, you can always use Path.Combine() to "map" (combine...) a file name with a folder name (Application.StartupPath, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinForm application you don't need to use Server.MapPath.

Instead you can use combine path relative to your application StartupPath.

For example:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to find file in directory you can use function, example:

```
string fileNameToFind = "*.txt";
string directoryToSearch = @"C:\Path\To\Folder\To\Search\In";
string[] files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(directoryToSearch, fileNameToFind, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string f in files)
{
  Console.WriteLine("File: " + f);
}

Console.WriteLine("Total of " + files.Length + " files found.");
```

Comment: for example if i have a file named "myTestClass.xml" somewhere in my system, and i need to get the physical path, what i need to do in button click event

Comment: @vettori: What do you mean by "somewhere"? Are you looking for a function that searches your hard drive for a given file?

Comment: @Kamil Lach yes it would search and find the location of file

Comment: There is not build in function for that (as far as i know), you need to write recursihr function for searching file in your system.

Comment: i've post example of search function.